# Not all records showing in SQL results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query that returns to me a list of Analysts with amount of claims they've filed and the amount. I know how many Analyst there are for a specific client (6). The problem I'm having is when I run the query, only 4 pop up. If i comment out the WHERE clause (which gives me back each Analysts specific amount), I get all the Analyst, but their amounts are all the same. How do I get back the missing Analysts? I don't care if they return 0... as a matter of fact, that's what i'm trying to figure out along with the count and sums. All help is greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
SELECT 
    a.auditorID, 
    fName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT case when claims.dateon >='20200726' AND claims.dateon <= '20200909' AND entries.errorCode NOT IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') then claims.rID end) as rTotal1,
    SUM(case when claims.dateon >= '20200726' AND claims.dateon <= '20200909' AND entries.errorCode NOT IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') then entries.refundDue else 0.0 end) as rate1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT case when claims.dateon >='20200726' AND claims.dateon <= '20200909' AND entries.errorCode IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') then claims.rID end) as pTotal1,
    SUM(case when claims.dateon >= '20200726' AND claims.dateon <= '20200909' AND entries.errorCode IN('DP','RB','DN','WP','WA','CE','RC','SI','CI','PE','OV') then entries.refundDue else 0.0 end) as payment1
    
FROM auditors a

INNER JOIN
(
SELECT auditorID, assignments.clientID FROM assignments INNER JOIN assignmentCarriers ac ON ac.acID=Assignments.acID WHERE isAssignment='True' GROUP BY auditorID, assignments.clientID
) tAssignments ON tAssignments.auditorID=a.auditorID

INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT clientID, code FROM clients WHERE code='ABBL'
) tClients ON tClients.clientID=tAssignments.clientID

INNER JOIN claims ON claims.client=tClients.code
INNER JOIN entries ON claims.rID = entries.rid

WHERE claims.auditorID=a.auditorID

GROUP BY a.auditorID, fName


ORDER BY fName
```

Here's what I'm getting when I run the code without the SUM or COUNT...

```
98  User 1
99  User 2
21  User 3
61  User 4
103 User 5
172 User 6
```

Here's with the constraints

```
98  User 1  17    147346.3000   1    9451.1600
21  User 2  0     0.0000        21   182958.5100
61  User 3  5     36970.0000    81   353592.8000
103 User 4  534   319697.5774   58   234350.7900
```

Comment: I think claims table doesnt have all auditorIDs. Because of this `claims.auditorID=a.auditorID` join is not working. And removing where clause giving you repeating records - this means some cross join is occurring.

Comment: Some sample data would help here. Try moving that `where` clause condition after the `claims` join and make it a [`left join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#join-type). Something like `LEFT JOIN claims ON claims.client=tClients.code AND claims.auditorID=a.auditorID` (_no_  `where` clause).

Comment: even if claims doesn't contain auditors, how do i show them? This is vital information considering these auditors aren't filing claims.

Comment: If the claims _must_ always be shown, why not start there? `select * from claims left join auditors on ...`

Comment: @Sanders... so i removed the where clause and tried what you told me and it gave me the same results. The query doesn't begin with claims, actually begins with the list of Auditors specific to this client. Each auditor is assigned a client. So basically, i'm getting the list of assigned auditors and then moving from there

Comment: Please update your question towards a complete [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This includes sample data and expected result.

Comment: It's been updated.

Comment: *even if claims doesn't contain auditors, how do i show them?* Try changing `INNER JOIN claims...` to `FULL JOIN claims...`

Comment: Nothing changed whatsoever